# doesn't work my strict inequality formula in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below command for our file, but it doesn't work.
when first parameter is less than second parameter, it is not work!

```
Private Sub auto_close()
' This macro hides sheets when the user closes the workbook
' It is a "Private Sub" to prevent it being listed with outher macros

On Error Resume Next

' When workbook is closed hide sheets required
If Sheets("PRICE").Rang("P5") > Sheets("SadraTajhiz").Range("P5") Then

If Sheets("SadraTajhiz").Range("P5") = "0" Then'
Worksheets("PAYMENT").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Application.Goto Sheets("PRICE").Range("A2")
Else
Worksheets("PAYMENT").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Application.Goto Sheets("SadraTajhiz").Range("A2")
End If

Else

Application.Goto Sheets("PRICE").Range("A2")
Worksheets("PAYMENT").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This is pretty obvious with the following line of code: `If Sheets("PRICE").Rang("P5") > Sheets("SadraTajhiz").Range("P5") Then`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: And you have a typo in that line of code; so would error (Rang => Range)

Comment: The typo in your `If` statement mentioned by @Flephal is causing an error, your `On Error` then says to resume at the next statement, so it is going into the `True` leg of the `If` statement in all cases.